# how to change timestamps generated by NOW() function into dates after a certain period

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column where non-volatile time function BNOW() has been mannually input at different times.
To put it simple, say, in col A

```
A1=BNOW()       it's value=3/25/2013 10:00:23

A2=BNOW()       it's value=3/25/2013 10:03:09
```

I want values of A1 and A2 to be changed to dates only (ie, 3/25/2013) 10 mins after each's original time stamps. How should I code this in VBA?

What I want is to let Excel monitor each cell with BNOW() and automatically change the value to dates 10mins after each's time value, respectively.

PS: BNOW() is a non-volatile user-defined function of the Excel NOW().

Comment: any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application.Ontime in the worksheet Change event to call a sub that will change the cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    If Target.Formula = "=NOW()" Then
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'DoIt """ & Target.Parent.Name & "!" & Target.Address & """'"
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

The sub to change the cell can look something like this:

```
Public Sub DoIt(t As String)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Range(t).NumberFormat = "General"
Range(t).Value = Format(Range(t).Value, "m/dd/yyyy")
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This sub must be in a code module, not in the sheet's class module. Also, because of limitations in calling subs with parameters via Application.Ontime I think the sheet name can't contain spaces.

Comment: thanks @aardvark123 I didn't know that a parameter could be passed to the sub to be called by Application.OnTime.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in VBA using the NumberFORMAT property:

```
cell.NumberFormat="dd/mm/yy;@"
```

this will NOT change the value, only the way it is presented as Text.

Also, you could change the value to a text string:

```
activecell.Value=day(activecell) & "/" & month(activecell) & "/" & year(activecell)
```

BUT, the best option is to do it using Excel formatting/Conditional Formatting

Hope this helps

Philip

Comment: sorry, what I want is to let Excel monitor each cell with BNOW() and automatically change the value to dates 10mins after each's time value, respectively.

Comment: that's not a good idea, but maybe you could use a Timer control or library, and have it running continuoulsy.